# PHP and SimpleXMLElement: finding location of xpath result in string

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm using `SimpleXMLElement` to evaluate an XPath query.

```
<!-- $document -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hey>
    <name>Donovan</name>
</hey>
```

Using the XPath `$xpath = "/hey/name"`, like:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($document);
$result = $xml->xpath($xpath);
```

Is there a way to get the location (in this case `30`) of the XMLElement `name` in the string `$document`?

Comment: It's just a string, so `strpos($document, '<name>')` will do.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski. I thought about that, but that's not going to work depending of the xml. For example, suppose I have two tags of the same kind (like `name`, for example), and the xpath looks like `/hey/name[2]`.

Comment: what do you mean by "location"?

Comment: @RobApodaca: I would like to know the position of the resulting XMLElement in the initial string. I was hoping in a way to get column and line number or something like that for each SimpleXMLElement found by the XPath query.

Comment: @Donovan I doubt you'll be able to accomplish something like that using SimpleXMLElement. You may want to re-evaluate your end goal to see if there is another way to get what you need. For example, maybe you only need the xml index of the name element?

Comment: @Donovan, do you want "the location (in this case 30)", or do you want the "column and line number", or do you want "something like that"?  Please make up your mind as each would require a different answer. We have no idea of your actual wants/needs, it may be something as simple as [getLineNo()](http://php.net/domnode.getlineno) or [getNodePath()](http://php.net/domnode.getnodepath) that you really want (those are DOM methods, but it's trivial to use them with SimpleXML too).

Comment: @salathe, both would be fine, but the location would be best. Anyway, I suppose this is not possible using SimpleXMLElement, so I will try if I can find a solution using `xml_parse`.

Comment: @salathe Thanks, getLineNo looks promis